# Why every infinite set (not only countable) contains countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Theorem.** Any infinite set $X$ contains countable infinite subset.

And set of natural numbers contain countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets.

Now why from this two follows that every infinite set (not only countable) contains countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets.

Comment: Any infinite set contains a countable subset, so it suffices to resolve this in the countable case (where it is easy).

Comment: @lulu You mean every infinite set?

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  Thanks for the correction.  I will edit now.

Comment: @lulu Ok   if we have that set of natural numbers contain countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets why from this follows that any countable subset of any infinite set $X$ contains also?

Comment: Should say:  this does depend on your choice of axioms.  In some systems, you can not prove that infinite sets must have countable subsets.  But, I imagine that this is not the sort of detail you are concerned with.

Comment: Fix a bijection, $F$,  between $\mathbb N$ and your countable subset.  If $\{S_i\}$ is your collection inside $\mathbb N$, then $\{F(S_i)\}$ works in your set.

Comment: Can any infinite set $X$  contain also  uncountably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets?

Comment: Of course not.  No countable set has uncountably many disjoint subsets.

Comment: It is silly question but can you say from what that follows?

Comment: Choose an element from each subset of your collection, that gives you an uncountable subset of your countable set.  Of course, I'm using AOC here (though I expect you don't need the full force of it).

Comment: And because every subset of countable set is countable it is contradiction yes?

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much!

Comment: No set can have a subset bigger than it (to speak informally).

Comment: Then why claim follows?

Comment: For the reason I said.  If there was an example, we could construct an uncountable subset of a countable set.

Comment: And why that gives contradiction?If set can have a subset bigger than it as you said?

Comment: I wrote "no set can have a subset bigger than it".

Comment: Ah sorry :))))))) thank you

Comment: @lulu If you post what you wrote as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I only wrote a sketch.  If you want to write up the details, you can post your own solution here.  That way people can review your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From theorem we can consider only countably infinite case.

Let's look at set of prime numbers $P=${$2,3,5,...$}.

and for every natural number $k$, $P_k=$ {$2^k,3^k,5^k,...$}

$P_1=P$,$P_k\cap P_1=\emptyset$ if $k\neq1$

So set of natural numbers contains countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets.

We can fix bijection $F$ between $\mathbb N$ and our countable infinite set.

Because set of natural numbers contains countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets let's say $\{S_i\}$, $F(S_i)$ will be  countably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets of our countable infinite set.

Also note given  infinite set X, it can't contain  uncountably infinite number of pair by pair disjoint countable infinite subsets(see in the comments).

Comment: I suggest exhibiting a solution for $\mathbb N$.  That's the crux of the argument, after all.

Comment: @lulu Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, that collection works.